# CoreGraphics - Clipping a gradient with a stroke

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

My CGContext has a path and a line width, this draws a nice black outline of my path in my `UIView`. Great. Now I’m trying to colour this stroke, and although the `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` method isn’t bad, I want a more vibrant colour so decided to use a gradient.

The problem is there’s no `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithGradient` method in iOS or (that I can see) anything similar. So I figured I must be able to draw a gradient which is clipped to the stroke I’ve drawn.

To do that, I’ve drawn my gradient to my `UIView` and now the `UIView` has a gradient background which fills the view.

So now I have a black stroke and my gradient. Great. But how do I clip one to the other? So it looks like my stroke has the colour of the gradient?

I’ve called `CGContextClip` between creating the stroke and the gradient, but this doesn’t clip the gradient to the stroke, it just clips the gradient to the fill of the path. The only thing I want to clip the gradient to is the stroke.

Any ideas?

Here’s my `drawRect`:

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

let path = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(path())

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, myLineWidth)
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)
CGContextAddPath(context, path)

CGContextClip(context)

CGContextStrokePath(context)

let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colourSpace,
    [startColour.CGColor, endColour.CGColor],
    [0.0, 1.0])

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context,
    gradient,
    CGPoint.zeroPoint,
    CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height),
    CGGradientDrawingOptions.allZeros)
```

Answer (score 1):

So the simple `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath` method is what I needed. Docs could be a bit clearer as to state what is being sent to the context, but there we go...